# Is there a way to implement manifest.appcache within firebase hosting?

Tags: android, firebase, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm looking to implement [HTML5 manifest.appcache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) and [Android web app manifest](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android) in my firebase web application, but there seems that .appcache files doesn't work while within a firebase hosting.

Does anyone know if there's a way to configure it, such as the firebase.json configuration file?

Comment: We just deployed a manifest.appcache file to Firebase hosting and found it was being served with the correct mime-type. What steps did you take? What "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Unless you provide some steps to help us reproduce the problem you are having, we won't be able to help much. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I deployed a manifest.appcache file on my firebase hosting, and the images and javascript files were being downloaded all the time.

I visited today again the same web site, and it seems now they're being cached, seems that it needs some time to star beign cached locally.

Comment: OK, great to hear that it started working. For a next time, we'll be best able to help you if you provide the steps that you took (e.g. a minimal code snippet, the commands that you ran), the output that you got and the output that you expected to get. Failing those, questions will attracts mostly comments for more information, which takes valuable attention away from actually solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, first time posting here.